# Open Office Calc, round to next largest multiple of 5?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I'm trying to get a formula to work that always rounds to the next largest multiple of 5.

For example, if I calculate 248, and I use MROUND, I get the correct 250, but if the calculation returns 246, MROUND will round down to 245, not the needed 250.

Its a problem with interacting with real world objects, a 246mm foot simply doesn't fit in a 245mm shoe.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [CEILING function](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/CEILING)

> Rounds a number to the nearest multiple of a significance value. In most cases, the number is rounded up (toward +∞).

```
=CEILING(A1,5)
```

**Demo example**

The demo is done with LibreOffice Calc, but the working is the same in OpenOffice Calc, Excel, Google Sheets.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!